# Why does the websocket stop?

Tags: python, websocket

```
import json
import amino
from websocket import create_connection
from time import time as timestamp

client = amino.Client()
client.login(email=<email>, password=<password>)
subclient = amino.SubClient(comId=<comid>, profile=client.profile)

def listen():
    ws = create_connection(
            f"wss://ws1.narvii.com?signbody={client.device_id}%7C{timestamp() * 1000}&sid={client.sid}")
        while True:
            data = json.loads(ws.recv())
            if data["t"] == 1000 and data["o"]["chatMessage"]["type"] == 0:
                try:
                    if data["o"]["chatMessage"]["content"] == "!ping":
                        subclient.send_message(chatId=data["o"]["chatMessage"]["threadId"], message="Pong!")
                    print(data["o"]["chatMessage"]["content"])
                except:
                    print("ERROR")
listen()
```

The problem is that after 5 minutes of successful work, for some reason he stops receiving messages from chats, while the program does not crash. What could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: are you sure the remote site is not rate limiting requests?

Comment: Could be a proxy / server timeout. Depending on your configuration, if data isn't exchanged for a while, a timeout occurs (usually after 50 seconds or so), causing the intermediary / server to disconnect the socket. The solution to this is often to ping the socket before a timeout can occur.

Comment: @Myst Yes, I heard about this, can I have an example of how to solve this problem?

Comment: @lynx1 - I'm no python expert, but I think you will either need to use a different loop / approach or setup pinging from the server. Right now you are blocking on `read`, which won't allow you to review a possible timeout or to send ping messages. You could add another thread that will `sleep(40)` and send a `ping`, but that would be a dirty and wasteful hack.